# Moving text files from windows to linux with special charecters

Tags: linux, special-characters

I was copying a text file encoded as utf-8 from windows to Linux which has lot of special character's. All of them are being retained in Linux except one character.

The character is "▯ White vertical rectangle".

When I move the file to Linux it shows as  ^? in vi editor.

Please help me out

Comment: You can open the file in vi/vim and try `:edit ++enc=UTF-8` to ensure the character set is `UTF-8`, `:write ++enc=UTF-8` to save. If there is no corresponding character in the `latin-1` character set (or your default), that matches the white vertical rectangle, then conversion may not be possible.

Comment: I am new to Linux, when I made sure the encoding in windows is utf-8, does the encoding change when I moved it to Linux? Because most of the characters are carrying except the specified one.